# Detect when any of the controls within a Group Box has changed

Tags: vb.net, controls, groupbox

I have an 'Apply' button on a form which initially has the property `Enabled = False`, but when a control within any `GroupBox` on the from is changed `Enabled = True` should be set.

I have several GroupBox controls on the form, and I was hoping that I could simply check if a control within any of these had changed. However, while it seems you can hook to the `ControlAdded` and `ControlRemoved` events, there is no `ControlChanged` event.

So I'm currently setting this up as below (there are a lot more than 5 controls to check in reality).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, as I can see this causing issues in the future (if options are ever added to a Group for example)? Thanks.

```
Private Sub ControlChanged(sender As Object,
                           e As EventArgs) Handles txtUsername.KeyUp,
                                                   chkRestoreIEFavourites.CheckedChanged,
                                                   chkRestoreNicknames.CheckedChanged,
                                                   chkRestoreDesktop.CheckedChanged,
                                                   chkRestoreQuickLaunch.CheckedChanged
    Me.btnApply.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If they are just options that will work, but if the CheckChanged event  for a given Chk is to ever do something on its own, you used its event for this.  In that case, it would probably be better to enable the button as part of the check event.   KeyUp seems an odd choice for a TB too

Comment: Unfortunately I do not currently hook to events from all controls that should be checked for this purpose, so I cannot implement the first part of your suggestion. Also, how so is `KeyUp` an odd choice? Thanks.

Comment: KeyUp would fire on each key press. This could be a backspace, a tab, a return key. In otherwords you would enable the button while the textbox may not have any text at all. This may not be an issue in your case dependent on any other validation you may do. Possibly .TextChanged would be a better event.

Comment: Ok, so basically the `KeyUp` event of a Textbox would fire if I tabbed out of that box, where as with `TextChanged` it would not? Fair enough, I'll look to make some amendments to my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, I've figured out a way of doing this...

The below now adds handlers (on `Shown`) so that if any `CheckBox` or `TextBox` within a `GroupBox` on the form is changed, the `Apply` button is set to `Enabled = True`. I also remove the handles when the from is `Closing`.

Whether this is the best way of doing it I don't know, but for now it's the only way that I know. Comments welcome!

```
Private Sub formSettings_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SetupChangeHandlers()
End Sub

Private Sub formSettings_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    SetupChangeHandlers(Remove:=True)
End Sub

Private Sub SetupChangeHandlers(Optional ByVal Remove As Boolean = False)

    For Each GroupBox As GroupBox In Me.sptSettings.Panel2.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)() _
                                       .OrderBy(Function(b) b.TabIndex)
        For Each Control As Control In GroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of Control)() _
                                       .OrderBy(Function(b) b.TabIndex)

            If TypeOf Control Is CheckBox Then
                Dim Checkbox = CType(Control, CheckBox)
                If Not Remove Then : AddHandler Checkbox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf GroupBoxControl_Changed
                Else : RemoveHandler Checkbox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf GroupBoxControl_Changed
                End If

            ElseIf TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
                Dim TextBox = CType(Control, TextBox)
                If Not Remove Then : AddHandler TextBox.TextChanged, AddressOf GroupBoxControl_Changed
                Else : RemoveHandler TextBox.TextChanged, AddressOf GroupBoxControl_Changed
                End If

            ElseIf TypeOf Control Is MaskedTextBox Then
                Dim MaskedTextBox = CType(Control, MaskedTextBox)
                If Not Remove Then : AddHandler MaskedTextBox.TextChanged, AddressOf GroupBoxControl_Changed
                Else : RemoveHandler MaskedTextBox.TextChanged, AddressOf GroupBoxControl_Changed
                End If

            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that you will need to import `System.Linq` and `System.Windows.Forms` to use this solution.